# Channels 404 page shows 0 reputation

Tags: bug, top-bar, 404-not-found, stack-overflow-for-teams

When I go to a page in Channels which doesn't exist, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/404), a link to my profile is shown but it tells me I have 0 reputation:

[image]

Comment: You gotta be a member of the 404 team to earn rep on that page.

Comment: That'd be https://stackoverflow.com/c/404/

Comment: Ah, I didn't actually check the link you posted. Probably worth noting that posting that essentially gives anyone who clicks it a red carpet into your channel due to how you've configured it...

Comment: Yeah, we intend to go public soon, but thanks for the concerns.

Comment: It doesn't just display 0 rep. The user ID and slug are also missing from the link. It seems like a local view model is uninitialized.

Comment: Random: _"In order to confirm access, we need to verify that you have an email address from one of the following domains: \@live.com, \@charcoal-se.org, \@yahoo.com, \@gmail.com, \@icloud.com, \@hotmail.com"_ I'm curious as to why this restriction? I use my own domain. Is this a Channels limitation or something the Channel owners set for some reason? I could ask this as its own question but want to quickly check with OP first as if it's something they set then no global answer exists

Comment: (backslashes added so I can actually post it!)

Comment: It's set by the Channel's owner. Not everyone of us has an @charcoal-se.org email address.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info, but not everyone of us wants to use a Live, Yahoo, Gmail, iCloud or Hotmail email address either! Why not allow any email address?

Comment: Also is it deliberate that it says "TEAMS" not "CHANNELS" on the LHS? I haven't really been keeping up with all the new SE tech but I thought Teams was summat else

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you can only sign up to a channel/team with an email of a whitelisted domain. It's actually supposed to be limited to @@charcoal-se.org, but the channel admins figured it would be funny to allow those generic domains too.

Comment: @Floern: Okay thanks for the info

Comment: @Floern It wasn't done to be "funny". It was done to facilitate users signing up. Most users interested in the Team/Channel don't have a \@charcoal-se.org email address and are not expected to get one. At a minimum, there appears to be a limitation in the hosting account as to how many email addresses can be configured. There are also transparency issues for the project (i.e. keeping non-admin-private information public). Thus, there was/is a legitimate reason to have those domains white-listed.

Comment: I thought the official term was Channels, too; but [*"Stack Overflow for Teams is the product name.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364405/874188) In the grand scheme of things, that's probably a better name, though right now Teams sounds like "that other thing which they stopped doing" to many of us still.

Comment: I notice the domains are no longer whitelisted.