# Tag [channels] on Meta redirects to [stackoverflow-for-teams]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, meta, stack-overflow-for-teams

[[channels]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channels) redirects to [[stackoverflow-for-teams]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams) -- should it perhaps now be the other way around?

<del>Also, the [tag info for this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stackoverflow-for-teams/info) is crude, unintelligible, and potentially misleading.
I was going to edit the tag info summary but it seems the wrong thing to do until the synonym is reversed or perhaps otherwise clarified.
 (Details elided; see edit history.)</del>

So, should the current synonym be removed, reversed, or something else; and how do we take things from there?

Comment: Joe created the synonym and my understanding is that the product is called Teams now.

Comment: @Catija Thanks - I have now updated the tag info roughly like I originally planned, but adapted to this twist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow for Teams is the product name. So, the synonym is correct. Thanks for updating the tag info.